# Google map not displaying on the first load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](http://larsgebhardt.de/parse-xml-with-ruby-on-rails-paperclip-and-nokogiri/) for loading a gpx file but with rails 4.2.6. I've got it working but I have a problem that when I load the tracks#index view and I click on the track to see it, it doesn't load the Google Map (the rest of the page loads) but if I right click on the link and open it in another tab or type the url myself it loads the Google Map fine.

The track#index view was generated with scaffolding:

```
<%= link_to track_path(track), class: 'btn btn-xs', title: "#{ t('.show', default: t('helpers.links.show')) }" do %>
        <%= glyph 'info-sign' %>
      <%- end -%>
```

When I click on it calls the tracks#show controller:

```
  def show
@track = Track.find(params[:id])
respond_to do |format|
  format.html  
  format.json {
    render :json => @track.to_json(:methods => [:polyline],:only => [:name])
  }
end
```

end

polyline is just a method for encoding the gpx points as a polyline using the Polyline gem.

The tracks#show view load the map with:

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 200px; margin-bottom: 20px"></div>
```

The initialization code for the maps is in coffeescript:

```
gm_init = ->
  gm_center = new google.maps.LatLng(38, 0)
  gm_map_type = google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE 
  map_options = {center: gm_center, zoom: 8, mapTypeId: gm_map_type}
  new google.maps.Map(@map_canvas,map_options);
$ ->
  map = gm_init()
```

What I don't understand is why when loading /tracks/1 works ok when the clicking on the index to load the same url it doens't show the mat just and empty area

Answer (score 3):

It's a problem with turbolinks and Rails 4. Turbolinks doesn't load the js you need to load the maps. To solve it I've added `'data-no-turbolink':  true` to the link that loads the page with the map:

```
<%= link_to track_path(track), class: 'btn btn-xs', title: "#{ t('.show', default: t('helpers.links.show')) }", 'data-no-turbolink':  true do %>
```

There are other ways but i think this is the easiest.

Comment: Although it's the easiest way, it's not the wisest. Turbolinks, even though it's a pain in the ass to 'master', it's very useful at what it does. Try my method, that should work. Helped me anyway!

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely an issue with Turbolinks. I'm hitting this problem as well in my app.
I have fixed my issues by wrapping my JS inside

`$(document).on('ready turbolinks:change turbolinks:load', function() { });`

Comment: It's Turbolinks that is causing the trouble not Sprockets

Comment: @PerseP That's what I meant, sorry.

Comment: Yes it also works but this is for version 5 of Turbolinks, for the classic version I used:
`$(document).on "page:change", ->
     your_js_here
`